# implementación de una Interface

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación y necesito enviar mensajes de los procesos de los hijos en la forma padre (MDI) en un TollStripStatusLabel, para lo que cree la interface:

```
public interface IForm
{
    void MDIMsg(string Msg);
}
```

En la forma MDI coloco:

```
    public partial class MdiParent : Form, IForm
.
.
.
        #region IForm
        public void MDIMsg(string Msg)
        {
             sttMain.Text = Msg;
            if (Msg != "Ready.")
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                sttMain.BackColor = Color.Black;
                sttMain.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                sttMain.BackColor = Color.White;
                sttMain.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        #endregion
```

En una forma hijo tengo:

```
    IForm MyInterface = this.Owner as IForm;
    if (MyInterface != null)
        MyInterface.MDIMsg("Looking for file...");
```

Pero el if siempre da nulo, por lo que la siguiente instrucción no se ejecuta. Alguien podría indicarme que estoy haciendo mal por favor. Gracias anticipadas`introducir el código aquí`

Comment: Has probado con `MdiParent` en lugar de `Owner`?

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh tu comentario me hizo el día. Esa es la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Click derecho en la raiz del proyecto y agregar clase y selecciona Interface, dentro de la clase que te crea pones:

```
void datafromManual(string mivar);
```

En el formulario hijo declaras

```
public Interface1 datos { get; set; }
```

Le pasas los datos que quieres mandar al formulario padre desde el evento del boton o lo que quieras

```
 datos.datafromManual("Tus datos para el form padre");
```

creas un metodo donde vas a recibir los datos del hijo en el padre

```
public void datafromManual(string mivar)
    {
      textPadre.Tex = mivar;
    }
```

Cuando llames a tu formulario hijo pones

```
Formhijo frmmanual = new Formhijo();
        frmmanual.datos = this;
        frmmanual.ShowDialog();
```

Comentas que tal te ha ido.